# Как загрузить данные Linq запроса в ListView (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, linq

Код где я хочу получить сведения о данном отеле (Данные хранятся в бд) и загрузить это в `ListView`

```
using (ApplicationContext context = new ApplicationContext())
{
    var test = context.Hotel.Where(x1 => x1.nameOfHotel == "Hotel Rendez-Vous Batignolles").Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
    var currentHotels = test;
    LViewHotels.ItemsSource = currentHotels;
}
```

Класс созданный с помощью Entity Framework

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     Этот код создан по шаблону.
//
//     Изменения, вносимые в этот файл вручную, могут привести к непредвиденной работе приложения.
//     Изменения, вносимые в этот файл вручную, будут перезаписаны при повторном создании кода.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace WPF_Project
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class Hotel
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Hotel()
        {
            this.ListOfChanges = new HashSet<ListOfChanges>();
            this.ListOfRooms = new HashSet<ListOfRooms>();
            this.photosOfHotels = new HashSet<photosOfHotels>();
        }
    
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string nameOfHotel { get; set; }
        public int idOfCity { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string hotelDescription { get; set; }
        public int countOfStars { get; set; }
        public byte[] ImagePreview { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> idListOfChanges { get; set; }
    
        public virtual City City { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ListOfChanges> ListOfChanges { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ListOfRooms> ListOfRooms { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<photosOfHotels> photosOfHotels { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Выскакивает следующее исключение `The type '<CrtImplementationDetails>.Exception' and the type 'System.Exception' both have the same simple name of 'Exception' and so cannot be used in the same model. All types in a given model must have unique simple names. Use 'NotMappedAttribute' or call Ignore in the Code First fluent API to explicitly exclude a property or type from the model.`

Не знаю, что с этим делать

[image: Скрин исключения]

Интерфейс

```xml
<Page x:Class = "WPF_Project.HotelList"
          xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:mc = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
          xmlns:d = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
          xmlns:local = "clr-namespace:WPF_Project"
          mc:Ignorable = "d" 
          d:DesignHeight = "600" d:DesignWidth = "1080"
          Title = "HotelList" ShowsNavigationUI = "False">
        <Grid Background = "#371f60">
            <ListView Grid.Row = "1" Name = "LViewHotels" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = "Disabled" HorizontalAlignment = "Center">
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation = "Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Width = "1280">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height = "70*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height = "80*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width = "10*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width = "20*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            
                            <Image Width = "320" Height = "auto" Stretch = "UniformToFill" HorizontalAlignment = "Left">
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <Binding Path = "ImagePreview"/>
                                </Image.Source>
                            </Image>
    
                            <TextBlock Text = "{Binding nameOfHotel}" x:Name="popa" Foreground = "White" FontSize = "20" Height = "40" Width = "720" VerticalAlignment = "Center" 
                                       TextAlignment = "Center" HorizontalAlignment = "Center" TextWrapping = "Wrap" Margin = "0, 16, 0, 224" Grid.Row = "0" Grid.Column = "1" />
    
                            <TextBlock Text = "{Binding StringFormat = {}Stars {0}, Path = countOfStars}" Foreground = "White" FontSize = "20" Height = "40" Width = "720" VerticalAlignment = "Center" 
                                       TextAlignment = "Center" HorizontalAlignment = "Center" TextWrapping = "Wrap" Margin = "0, 56, 0, 184" Grid.Row = "0" Grid.Column = "1"/>
    
                            <TextBlock Text = "{Binding StringFormat = {}Phone {0}, Path = phoneNumber}" Foreground = "White" FontSize = "20" Height = "40" Width = "720" VerticalAlignment = "Center" 
                                       TextAlignment = "Center" HorizontalAlignment = "Center" TextWrapping = "Wrap" Margin = "0, 96, 0, 144" Grid.Row = "0" Grid.Column = "1"/>
    
                            <TextBlock Text = "{Binding StringFormat = {}Address {0}, Path = address}" Foreground = "White" FontSize = "20" Height = "40" Width = "720" VerticalAlignment = "Center" TextAlignment = "Center" 
                                       HorizontalAlignment = "Center" TextWrapping = "Wrap" Margin="0, 136, 0, 104" Grid.Row = "0" Grid.Column = "1"/>
    
                            <Button Tag = "{Binding}" Content = "Enter" Click="Button_Search_Room_Click" Width = "120" Height = "30" BorderBrush = "{x:Null}" Foreground = "#371f60" Background = "White" FontSize = "15" Grid.Column = "1" 
                                    Margin="520, 250, 0, 0"/>
                            
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
    
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Вам mvvm что то говорит? Попробуйте отделить логику получения данных. Убедитесь, что данные получаете, а потом список этих данных присвойте к datacontext. И оттуда можете биндиться к itemcource

Comment: Cruz21, У меня проблема пока в том, что при запросе linq выскакивает исключение следующего содержания : "The type '<CrtImplementationDetails>.Exception' and the type 'System.Exception' both have the same simple name of 'Exception' and so cannot be used in the same model. All types in a given model must have unique simple names. Use 'NotMappedAttribute' or call Ignore in the Code First fluent API to explicitly exclude a property or type from the model."
И я не понимаю с чем это связано

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18638741/the-type-company-model-user-and-the-type-company-core-model-user-both-have-t